# Append CGRect vertically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Two separate CGRect with same size and same originate points but different content.

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 600);
CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 600);
```

And I would like to append `rect2` at the bottom of `rect1`:

```
+-----------------------------+
|                             |
|                             |
|           Rect1             |
|                             |
|                             |
|-----------------------------|
|                             |
|                             |
|           Rect2             |
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
```

Could someone please show me how to achieve this? Thank you.

update:

```
- (CGRect)combineCGRect:(CGRect)rect1 f2:(CGRect)rect2 {
    rect2 = CGRectOffset(rect2, 0, rect1.size.height);
    return CGRectUnion(rect1, rect2);
}

NSRect IR1 =[someNSView frame];
CGRect tmp2 = [self combineCGRect:NSRectToCGRect(IR1) f2:NSRectToCGRect(IR1)];
```

Comment: Which part of `CGRect` reference guide you didn't understand?

Comment: `rect1` and `rect2` was saved at difference stage. And I want to combine both CGRect into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow  you correctly you are misunderstanding rectangles:

> Two separate `CGRect` with same size and same originate points but **different content**.

A `CGRect` itself does not have content, it is just an origin, width and height. What you appear to be trying to do is construct a single *image* by combining rectangular areas from two other images. To do this you need to create a suitable sized drawing buffer and then copy the rectangular areas from your source images into this buffer. It's not overly complicated but you need to do some reading and learn about some types. You can start with the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/GraphicsContexts/GraphicsContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH203-BCIJFBJJ), [`NSGraphicsContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgraphicscontext?language=objc), and [`NSImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage?language=objc) - you'll probably be using a method such as `drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:` to draw your rectangular areas from your source images into your graphics context.

If after reading the docs and designing your code you have problems with it ask a new question, include your code, and explain the problem. Someone will undoubtedly help you.

HTH

Comment: Thank you sir. `NSImage` is what I'm trying on now. Looks promising to me. So far so good. :)

Answer (score 1):

`CGRectUnion(rect1, rect2)` will give you the smallest rectangle that completely contains both rectangles. If they're the same width and one is directly beneath the other, that will give you the answer you want.

If they both have the same origin then you'll have to manually make a new one by adding the height of the second rect to the height of the first one. There isn't a built-in function for that.

To simply move the origin of the second rectangle so it is beneath the other:

`rect2 = CGRectOffset(rect2, 0, rect1.size.height);`

Comment: One can use `CGRectOffset` to offset one of the rectangles by the origin of the other rectangle.

Comment: Thank you, sir. But both CGRect was saved at difference stage. Hence, they have the same originate point (0,0). Is there anyway to move or assign `rect2` beneath `rect1`?

Comment: @user2131907 ah, I misunderstood what you wanted. I've edited the answer

Comment: @jrturton : I've added a function above. I just give the same image to it and were expected to have a long image that has two same image on top and down. However, I only got a large image with `blank` on top and input image on the bottom.

Comment: it sounds like your problem isn't about rectangles, but about images. Please add more detail to your question - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: IR1 is the content of NSView, which will change periodically. I want to capture each changes and combine them vertically into a large (and long) image.

Comment: OK, so what are you doing with tmp2 in the code above? _that's_ where your problem is

Comment: `tmp2` just stores the combined CGRect (in this case, the same NSView content) and it will be passed to pasteboard by calling `writePDFInsideRect`. So I can paste it to imgur to see the final result. The expected result will be two NSView content on the top and bottom.